# ionic 2 - white screen in android 7 and 7.1

Tags: ionic2

I create ionic 2  app and test in genymotion with 4 device :

add min and target sdk version :

```
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="25" />
```

update ionic and cordova and android to last version and after build android

worked :

```
samsung galaxy s6 - 5.0.0 - API 21
samsung galaxy s6 - 6.0.0 - API 23
```

not working and see white screen

```
samsung galaxy s8 - 7.0.0 - API 24

samsung galaxy s6 - 7.1.0 - API 25
```

Comment: Dude, same problem, I had an s6 that ran it fine, now I upgraded to the S8 and I get the white screen too! Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: dont use genymotion for test  api 7 and 7.1 , I  use online android emulator and my application work very well on api 7 and 7.1